# Conversion of mp3 to flac results in file with longer duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I've noticed that when I convert an mp3 file to flac, the duration reported in the flac file will often differ from that of the source mp3 file.  Mostly this difference is negligible and can be ignored (perhaps a fraction of a second).

However, there are times when the timing is off by several seconds, and this causes my processing pipeline quite a bit of problem.

For instance, take this [podcast episode for example](http://media.blubrry.com/startupsrestofus/www.project98.com/podcast/startups-for-the-rest-of-us-448.mp3). If I run it through ffmpeg, I can see that it has a duration of:

`Duration: 00:52:38.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s`

If I then convert it to flac using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i startups-for-the-rest-of-us-448.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -f flac output.flac`

I can see that the duration of the flac file is:

`Duration: 00:52:45.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 133 kb/s`

Note there is an error message during conversion that states:

```
[mp3 @ 0x7fffd16d6780] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Does the difference in duration have have to do with the bitrate difference? When I listen to the file it sounds identical, I'm assuming the flac version must be ever so slightly slower as to gain the extra 7 seconds over the course of the podcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see this near the top of the ffmpeg log

```
Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

MP3s may not have an index so ffmpeg has to estimate duration, which it does using bitrate. Depending on bitrate variance, this estimate can be off.

Run `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -vn -f null -` and check the end of the log for an accurate estimate

```
size=N/A time=00:52:45.67 bitrate=N/A speed= 761x
```

Comment: Ok, so this is very interesting. Two things...
1) What exactly is that command doing?
2) When I load the mp3 file into a media player it reports the 00:52:38 time, not the 00:52:45... If I scrub to the end, the audio does indeed end properly at 00:52:38. Does the player somehow fudge this? Really if I were to get out a stopwatch and play the file from the beginning would I find that it really ran for 00:52:45 and not 00:52:38?

Comment: The command is decoding the entire audio and sending it to a null output. Inside that pipeline, ffmpeg measures the raw audio duration and that is the time you see. You can run `ffmpeg -i in -c copy out.mp3` to generate a new file for which ffmpeg will store the duration in a header.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks!  Doing the extra work to get the duration proper will take more time, but it'll at least allow me to proceed without manipulating my existing processing pipeline